# ClassNotFoundException when start tyrus standalone server

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception, grizzly, tyrus

I'm getting the following error on `server.start()` call:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerContainer
```

I also could not found a maven dependency for `GrizzlyServerContainer`.

Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
private WebSocketModulManager() {
        server = new Server("127.0.0.1", 30000, "/lightconsole", null, LightconsoleEndpoint.class);
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
```

[Maven Dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijlbb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I already did that, but it looks like that Intellij do not process my pom file. All other deps are putted through Intellij Project Configuration

Comment: I switched from IntelliJ depedency management to straight maven pom file. No all depdencies are solved.

Comment: If you have `<scope>test</scope>` then remove it from all tyrus dependencies. I had the same issue and removing this, the issue got resolved