ClassNotFoundException: GrizzlyServerContainer class not found (Tyrus)
I am working on a Java project where I want to run a HTTP server and Websocket-Server on top. I am using Tyrus and Grizzly.
Whenever I try to start my Websocket in the project, I get the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerContainer
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.spi.ServerContainerFactory.createServerContainer(ServerContainerFactory.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server.start(Server.java:199)

It looks like, there is something wrong with my dependencies. Meanwhile, I tried to add almost every Tyrus dependency out there to close down what's missing. What dependencies do I need to add in my build.gradle.kts to make this work?
I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284762/classnotfoundexception-when-start-tyrus-standalone-server that switching from IntelliJ Dependency Management to Maven Pom directly helped, but isn't there another solution?

It depends on what JDK, HTTP server, and WebSocket API version you use.
